# Find the Earlier time at half maximum height and Later time at half maximum height

Tags: gravity

You throw a baseball directly upward at time t = 0 at an initial speed of 12.1 m/s. What is the maximum height the ball reaches above where it leaves your hand? At what times does the ball pass through half the maximum height? Ignore air resistance and take g = 9.80 m/s2. Find the Earlier time at half maximum height and Later time at half maximum height.

For the maximum height, I got 7.4699 m. I do not know what I do next to find the earlier time at half the height or the later time.

Comment: You know the height (distance from the ground) the baseball will be at, as well as the baseball's initial velocity and its acceleration. Do you know of an equation that involves only distance, initial velocity, acceleration, and time?

Comment: Is it X = VoT + 1/2 AT^2 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! So that'll give you an equation that's quadratic in #t#. Do you know of a particular formula to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: So the equation will now be (9.8/2)T^2 + 12.2T - 7.4699
And the quadratic formula is (-b +- sqrt( b^2 - 4ac))/2a

Comment: Almost, the quadratic equation is right, but for your other equation, remember there should be a $\frac{1}{2}$ in front of the accleration, and remember that the acceleration is negative! Also, the problem asks for the time at *half* maximum, so your distance should be divided by two.